# Tree View of Related Items

Tags: web-part, document-library

**Scenario**

We have a document library on our portal which contains word documents. Lets say the word documents can be grouped according to title, for example:

Grouping 1 contains the titles: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-3-1. In this grouping, 1-1 is the parent of 1-2 and 1-3. Also, 1-3 is the parent of 1-3-1.

So these titles form a tree of related items. I would like to either use an existing WebPart, whether a built in webpart or a free one online, or build the webpart myself. The ideal WebPart will be pretty simple - just a tree of items where each item is a link that can be clicked on to open the item's page. The idea is that by viewing the related items in a tree the user is able to better visualize them.

**The Question**

Assuming I need to build this WebPart myself, what do I need to learn? I have decent knowledge of SharePoint 2007 but hardly any of SharePoint 2010. I've used C# and ASP.NET 2.0 before but consider myself amateur. I think I'll need some AJAX for this project so that's one thing. Hopefully this question wasn't too vague, I'm unsure where to begin.

Comment: @kit Why did you remove the 2010 tag? 2010 uses a different version of ASP.NET in addition to [possibly] different SP libraries, so shouldn't they be tagged separately? edit: Just viewed your edit comment. I disagree but I suppose you would know better.

Comment: Mostly I was just replacing it with the other two tags to be more specific. If you think that this question applies only to SharePoint 2010 only then feel free to add it back in. =)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this out of the box with additional metadata in the document library I believe.  If you created a field called Parent that is a lookup to the same list, you might be able to pull it off without any custom programming.

You'd use a standard list view web part, grouped by title then parent and that should get you the tree like structure.

Comment: You can group by title then parent without Metadata. You just choose the "Lookup" type then select the same list. However this doesn't give a tree structure it gives a group with MAX one level of indentation...